# Bind DNS Server

Tags: linux, dns, bind

`enter code here`I am setting up my primary DNS server. The reverse lookup appears to work fine, it is the forward lookups that seems to be the problem.

Here are my configurations files.

`/etc/default/bind9`:

```
RESOLVCONF=no
OPTIONS="-u bind -4"
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
acl "trusted" { 192.168.1.0; localhost; };
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    listen-on { 192.168.1.204; 127.0.0.1; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    forwarders { 
        192.168.1.254;
    };
// listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "example.home.local" {
    type master;
    file "etc/bind/zones/db.example.home.local";
    };

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.1.168.192";
    };
```

`/etc/bind/zones/db.example.home.local`:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ubuntuserver.example.home.local. root.example.home.local. (
                 14     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
;name servers - NS records
@   IN  NS  ubuntuserver.example.home.local.

;name servers - A records
ubuntuserver    IN  A   192.168.1.204

;subnet - A records
ubuntuweb   IN  A   192.168.1.208
```

`/etc/bind/zones/db.1.168.192`:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA example.home.local. root.example.home.local. (
                 11     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
@   IN  NS  UbuntuServer.

; PTR records
204 IN  PTR ubuntuserver.example.home.local.
208 IN  PTR ubuntuweb.example.home.local.
```

As mentioned earlier, the reverse lookup works fine. When I run

```
sudo named-checkzone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/db.1.168.192
```

the results are ok and also when I do an `nslookup` from a test client it is able to successfully resolve the IP address to the name.

However, when I run

```
sudo named-checkzone example.home.local /etc/bind/zones/db.example.home.local
```

it reports back

```
loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/db.example.home.local failed: unknown class/type
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` where you're missing a leading `/` from the database path:

```
file "etc/bind/zones/db.example.home.local";
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was probably something small that I just kept missing. I will correct that and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @DanW did that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I was still having problems. I ended up using dnsmasq in the end. Will come back to bind in the future but I appreciate the help greatly.